# Append text to control after data has been loaded - Winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a `TextBox` that is bound to a `DataSource` that loads text into the `TextBox` when the selected row changes in a `DataGridView`.

Suppose the `TextBox` displays the price of a certain item selected in the `DataGridView`. My textbox will now display "100", though I would like it to display "100 USD".

The databinding has been done in Visual Studio, and not programmatically.

I've tried the following, only with successful result when the form loads; after that it goes back to as nothing has changed.

```
   private void dgvItemList_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        textBoxPrice.AppendText(" USD");
    }
```

How can I achieve this without having to load the data programmatically and append the text at that point?

Answer (score 0):

this should provide the desired result:

it will format the values from the third column(i added this datatable as an example).

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Column1");
            dt.Columns.Add("Column2");
            dt.Columns.Add("Column3");
            dt.Rows.Add(3, 1,35);
            dt.Rows.Add(1, 3, 62);
            BindingSource s = new BindingSource();
            s.DataSource = dt;
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = s;
            Binding b = new Binding("Text", s, "Column3");
            b.Format += new ConvertEventHandler(b_Format);
            textBox1.DataBindings.Add(b);
        }

        void b_Format(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Value = e.Value.ToString() + " USD";
        }
```

in your case bind the binding source to your datasource then the binding source to the datagridview  and so on like the example.